# Why stamp a passport at LGW when only changing planes?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration, passport-stamps

Wife and I flew JFK-LGW-BCN.  At LGW, we were supposed to have 02:35 to change planes, but it was  actually much shorter.  Don't remember much other than some helpful people rushing us from place to place with my wife in a wheelchair.

But looking at our passports today, I see that both of them were stamped that date as entering UK with six month permission.

Before we were married, I changed planes several times in LGW or LHR without getting a stamp.  Why would it happen this time?

Comment: Possibly on previous trips you were able to transit "airside" but on this occasion it's possible that you had to pass through Immigration and go "landside" to check in for the BCN flight. If your LGW-BCN flight was with EasyJet this would be because hat airline does not pay the airport operator for airside transit/security facilities.

Comment: What airlines and terminals did you use for each of the flights?

Comment: I have a hard time finding any JFK-LGW flights. Which airline was that, and when?

Comment: More the a year ago, so all I have without a lot of digging is that it was March 2019.

Comment: @canonacer might have it.  I do remember it seemed quite a jaunt.